# Using ajax with php to pass values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm sure its a simple mistake that I am doing here, but I can't spot it!

I have a button, which when clicked opens up a new form, fairly simple with two input fields. Upon clicking "Ok" I want to submit that form and pass the variables to a php function within the same page.

At the beginning of the page I have

```
$action = $_POST['add_audit'];
```

Then my ajax looks like this:

```
function addAudit()
{
    $('#auditAddDialog').dialog('open');
}
$('#auditAddDialog').dialog({'autoOpen': false, 'modal' : true, 'buttons' : 
    [ { text: "Ok", click: function() {

        var auditDate = $('#datepicker').val();
        var e = document.getElementById("type");
        var auditType = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var add_audit = 'add_audit';
        var dialog = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index_logged.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'add_audit':add_audit, 'auditDate' : auditDate, 'auditType' : auditType},
            type: 'post',
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(json) { 
                if (json.status == 'S')
                    alert('New audit created!');

                    location.reload();
                    $( dialog ).dialog( "close" );

            },
            error: function() {}

        }); 

}}]});
```

At first, I can't see anything wrong here and don't see why it shouldn't work? But there is obviously an error somewhere because when I click the "OK" button on the form, I get the whole page in HTML as a response.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: Incidentally AJAX is *expected* to return the whole web page from a request such as this. You may want to create a discrete file which will return only what you want.

Comment: I'm wondering if you left the question and going to return at a later date to check up on comments/answers. While the good people are waiting, you may want to do what @JayBlanchard suggested and post the HTML for this. You can ping one of us (preferably Jay, since he's much better a JS than I am), or wait for (another) answer. Good luck with this.

Comment: @JayBlanchard you were partially right. What I was missing was the return for my function, since the js function expected a status for json variable. Returning that in my PHP code did the trick. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!